# Send an HttpPost request from Android, read Post from PHP

Tags: java, php, android, http, post

As I'm progressing through my Android learning in some spare time, I've encountered a strange behaviour of `HttpPost` request.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Make a simple POST request from Android application to Apache web-server running on my development PC and display the POSTed data from PHP script to which the form is sent.

My Android app's **Java code** resides inside an `Activity` as an `AsyncTask` as following:

```
private class DoSampleHttpPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CharSequence> {

    @Override
    protected CharSequence doInBackground(Void... params) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(baseUrl);

            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "someuser"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "somedata"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(form);

            Log.v("log", "making POST request to: " + baseUrl);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception happened: " + e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CharSequence result) {
        // this refers to a TextView defined as a private field in the parent Activity
        textView.setText(result);
    }

}
```

My **PHP code** is the following:

```
<?php
echo "Hello<br />";
var_dump($_SERVER);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo "Page was posted:<br />";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$var) {
        echo "[$key] => $var<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

And **finally the problem**:
As you can see, the `$_SERVER` contents is dumped, and in the output `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` has value `GET` despite the fact that I was actually making a `POST` request. Even if I try to dump the contents of `$_POST`, it's empty.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you visit the specified URL on your PC does it do a 302 redirect at all? You might need to specify a trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Comment: Amazing! That was the problem. and solved it immediately when I added the trailing slash at the end of the URL

Comment: @Jon post as answer; Trogvar accept answer :)

Comment: Absolutely!
@Jon, post as answer so I can accept it :) Thanks, man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to specify a trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Often Apache redirects requests that don't end in trailing slashes so that they do contain a trailing slash. That redirect is a GET redirect (without some tweaking), so all POST data is lost.